# Specify a list of columns to move ot the end of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select multiple columns and move them to the end of the dataframe. E.g. current dataframe is:

```
index  a   b   c
1      2   3   4
2      3   4   5
```

How can I specify a list l = ['a', 'b'] and use that to specify that those two columns be moved to the end of the dataframe resulting in:

```
index  c   a   b
1      4   2   3
2      5   3   4
```

Note: I do not want to specify all the columns in the dataframe, only the columns I want to move

Comment: dup question is to move columns to the beginning, but should be similar enough.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution to move your columns to the end:

```
def move_cols_to_end(df, cols):
    return df[[x for x in df.columns if not x in cols] + cols]

df = move_cols_to_end(df, ['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has a DataFrame method which will re-order columns as required. You could use:

```
newcols = ['c', 'a', 'b']

df = df.reindex(columns = newcols)
```

Answer (score 1):

[pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) offers some convenience functions for this:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.move(source = 'c', target = 'a', axis = 1)
       c  a  b
index
1      4  2  3
2      5  3  4

df.reorder_columns(['c'])
       c  a  b
index
1      4  2  3
2      5  3  4
```